# AttributeError: 'CustomAugment' object has no attribute '__name__' when saving TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been toying with data augmentation for TensorFlow image classification. I used a tutorial to make a custom augmentation class, code below and then loaded it into the model using Keras Lamda. Training works fine however when I try to save the model immediately after training it crashes with the error provided in the title.

I am extremely new to python but my understanding is that the class is supposed to have a hidden __ name __ variabile. What gives?

Custom augment class

```
class CustomAugment(object):
    def __call__(self, image):        
        # Random flips and grayscale with some stochasticity
        img = self._random_apply(tf.image.flip_left_right, image, p=0.6)
        img = self._random_apply(self._color_drop, img, p=0.9)
        return img

    def _color_drop(self, x):
        image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x)
        image = tf.tile(x, [1, 1, 1, 3])
        return x
    
    def _random_apply(self, func, x, p):
        return tf.cond(
          tf.less(tf.random.uniform([], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32),
                  tf.cast(p, tf.float32)),
          lambda: func(x),
          lambda: x)


data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(CustomAugment()),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
  ]
)
```

Using it in the model

```
model = Sequential([
  tf.keras.Input(shape=(160, 160, 3)),
  data_augmentation,
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(160, 160, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
#rest of model here
```

Crashes here

```
model.save('el_patho_maximo')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem

I had to simply add __ name __ (without the spaces) = CustomAugment in the CustomAugment class right before __ init __

Comment: I dont understand your solution. Could you please post how you solved it?

Comment: @JKnecht In the CustomAugment class from the question I simply had to add one more line that said
`_name_='CustomAugment'`. i added the line immediately after `class CustomAugment(object):`

Answer (score 1):

It's an indentation problem. In `_random_apply`, all the lines except for the first one are not indented correctly. Either put it in a single line or leave the space that is left automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer., Fixed the indentation but still getting the error.